# How to customize my timer display to show only minutes and seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimeinterval

My Timer is displaying Minutes and Hours, but once it gets to 60 minutes it restarts from 0 Minute.

- Should I get rid of the modulo ( % 60 ) for minutes.
- I would like my timer to display for ex: 80:45 ( basically not stopping at 60 min once it reaches 1 hour)

  ```
  var min = 0
  var sec = 0

  func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
       let interval = Int(interval)
       let seconds = interval % 60
       let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
       //let hours = (interval / 3600)// I don't need the hours 
       return String(format: "%02d:%02d",minutes, seconds)
   }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`% 60` means that it will spit out a minutes value that is the **remainder** when divided by 60(minutes). This is most probably because for time in the form hh:mm, you want it to go from 5:59 to 6:00, not 5:60. So changing the following line will give you what you seek.

`let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60 -> let minutes = interval / 60`